# Can I have on a single ruby installation multimple RubyGem Manager using RVM?

Tags: rubygems, rvm, versions

I'm using RVM to maintain different ruby installations.
But I would like to have, for a single ruby installation, different versions of RubyGems Manager.
I see that I can only have one only RubyGem Manager on each Ruby installation.
The reason for having different versions of RubyGem is that I'm installing a very old version of RoR applications that needs a old version of RubyGems but on the same version of Ruby I use for other projects, that want a newer RubyGem.
Do you know if it would be possible to install a new, separate, copy of Ruby where I can install a specific version of RubyGem and all gems I want? It seems that even gemset can't help to do what I need because it can only manage different versions of gems but on the same RubyGem Manager.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with [named rubies](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/named/) basically it goes down to:

```
rvm install 1.8.7-old
rvm use 1.8.7-old
rvm rubygems 1.3.6
```